# bash script: continue until .jpg exists on website

Tags: image, bash

I would like to do the following: bash script which starts on particular URL and continues until image exists on website. For example:

```
www.example.com/1.jpg
www.example.com/2.jpg
www.example.com/3.jpg
www.example.com/4.jpg
www.example.com/5.jpg
```

Script should continue for 1,2,3,4,5 and stop when it reaches 6 as there is no image anymore. I want to do it alone, but I need one thing: how to check if image exists?

Comment: Use `curl` trying to fetch the image. If it return true it means that it exists.

Comment: the `bash` part of it: `for i in {1..6}; do echo $i; done`

Comment: Do you have the list of URLs in a file? Or is it just incremental numbers?

Comment: incremental numbers :) nice answer fedorqui:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use wget:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while wget -q "www.example.com/image${i}.jpg"; do
    echo "Got $i"
    (( i++ ))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
host='www.example.com/'
i=1
while curl -I  --stderr /dev/null "${host}${i}.jpg" | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 200
do
echo "Do something"
i=$i++
done
```